# Joomla component - how to convert standard php form into joomla component

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-component

Currently i have been using an iframe component to display a php page that i have written. the reason i used iframe rather than writing a joomla component in the first place was for 2 reasons, the information that is displayed in that page is from a remote mssql sever and the second was that i didnt really understand how to write one.

Now i have completed the creation of the php page that i display within the iframe, but now i need to be able to have it inherent within the joomla site, for both display reasons and security.

basically its a single page that displays information in a bunch of drop down boxes and then a submit button is clicked and it posts that information to another php page that again queries the mssql server and displays the results based on the post from the previous page.

query.php, posts some variables to results.php and is displayed in a table.

i have the functionality perfect, but i dont understand the documentation i have read so far. is there any simple component i can see the code of so that i can try and work out whats going on?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at [http://docs.joomla.org/J3.1:Developing_a_MVC_Component/Introduction](http://docs.joomla.org/J3.1%3aDeveloping_a_MVC_Component/Introduction) and follow the process outlined.

Comment: ive had a read through a few tutorials, but i feel like im missing something obvious

Comment: I''m just finding your description a bit confusing, are you saying you have two database connections?

Comment: essentially yes. there is an mssql and a mysql connection, both databases hold different information. i sort of got around this issue by writing a module, but now im facing another issue. ill ask a new question.